# Codeigniter error log messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-logging

I have been using codeigniter for sometime now. But I am still new to it. And when I bump into some problem, its takes days to figure it out and solve it.

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: page_m
```

I usullay face these sort of errors too. However since I am using multiple hierarchy of classes (Controllers) I am not being able to figure it out.

Is there any way I could make codeigniter to log the error messages with the line number??

Comment: If you use UNIX system file names are case sensitive. I gets this issue when uploading to live UNIX server after completing my development in my windows system. Please make sure you use the exact model and file name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create model in Application/Models directory. and make sure you extend your CI_Model class.

eg. model name : my_model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class my_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the file name is the same as the name of the class?

If your file is `page_model.php` the class must start with `class Page_Model extends CI_Model`

And in your controller remember `$this->load->model('page_model');`